# How to extract second set of records based on timestamp column using MySQL

Tags: mysql

[image: ApplicationDateRecordset]

I took this column (datatype = timestamp) image from a MySQL result window from a query I executed. I have 14 records in this query result and what I'm trying to do is DELETE those records that have a timestamp that is 2 minutes later than the first set of rows (7).  Any suggestions/direction on how to accomplish this would be appreciated.  Hope this makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: So, to describe the query, you want to get the MAX(timestamp) of the 7 earliest records, add 2 minutes to it, and delete the records in that table that are equal to or later than that value. Right?

Comment: You mention the first set is 7 rows. Is that a fixed value, always the first 7 rows? Or are you grouping records in a dynamic way?

Comment: Kind of.  As you can see the second set of rows are approx 2 minutes later but yes it the 2nd set of records that have a timestamp that is later by approx 2 minutes.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It's always 7 rows in the first set of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE t.time > DATE_ADD(  SELECT MIN(t2.time)
                          FROM table t2
               , INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, delete records having timestamps greater than or equal to two minutes later than the latest timestamp of the first seven records:

```
DELETE FROM table t1
WHERE t1.ApplicationDate >= DATE_ADD(
  (SELECT MAX(t1.ApplicationDate) FROM (SELECT ApplicationDate FROM table LIMIT 7) t1)
  , INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
)
```

---

*Explanation:*

First we need to get the first 7 records:

```
SELECT ApplicationDate FROM table LIMIT 7
```

From that we need to get the `MAX` (latest) timestamp:

```
SELECT MAX(t1.ApplicationDate) FROM (...)
```

We can then feed that as the first parameter into the `DATE_ADD` function, and 2 minutes as the second parameter:

```
DATE_ADD((...), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
```

This gives us the target timestamp to use as a condition for deletion of records:

```
DELETE FROM table t1 WHERE t1.ApplicationDate >= (...)
```